# Count how many times a word appears in table view row

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my Table view I am adding rows dynamically via a button press.

The `detailTextLabel.text` varies depending on a pass or fail result obtained in another view

Im trying to figure out how to best check how many rows contain the word "Fail"

I thought maybe add a bool and count how many times flag is raised? However not sure how to count how many times a bool == YES?

```
 if(cell.textLabel.text && [cell.detailTextLabel.text rangeOfString:@"Fail"].location != NSNotFound){


        //count total amount of rows that  detailTextLabel.text == failed, need to count here?

 }
```

Or can I check all the rows `self.circuits.count` for the word fail perhaps?

Comment: Tableview rows are recycled.  Instead of counting the rows, you will probably want to loop through and count the model data that each row represents.  This way, you will get a proper count.

Comment: Split the string into an array, use RegEx, increase the range over time from a loop for the search you're doing now, or literally compare the characters doing similar. All are ways to solve this.

Comment: How are the Fail's being created?  The Fail's should be stored in a model and the Fail on the label is only the view of that model.  When you create the Fail text for the label you should first be setting that "Fail" in your model somewhere, then displaying the model on the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as opposed to iterating over all the objects to track which ones contain "fail" and which don't, why not just check for this condition when you add the row. Then, if it does contain "fail" you can just increment a number (which you can store where ever you want) and you can keep track of the total "fails".

```
self.someNumberToRemember ++ ;
```

Comment: That was my first attempt, if a row contained fail I counted up one and saved it as an int value in NSSUserdeafults, however when I did that it kept adding the total to the previous total so if 10 failed, every time time I passed the total count to another view it added 10 to the previous 10.  Sound like I was close on that way of doing it so will perceiver with my original idea